# How to publish Maven filtered resources in Tomcat server.core plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

In Eclipse, with a Maven Project and a Tomcat Server, classpath resources are published in this path:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/WebApp/WEB-INF/classes/
```

However, the published files are not filtered by Maven.

How to publish filtered resources in the wtpwebapps folder?

Comment: How is this filtering done? Is this supported by m2e-wtp?

Comment: @nitind there's a maven-resources-plugin that make the filter in the target folder, but in wtpwebapps of Tomcat the files are still not filtered, it seems that Eclipse is putting the original files, not the files produced by the build.